# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]' again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

In **Form2** I have this variable which I tried everything with and any modification leads to an error:

```
            string[] row = {
            ProcessName[Index],
            process.Id.ToString(),
            status,
            BytesToReadableValue(process.PrivateMemorySize64),
            extraProcessInfo.Username,
            extraProcessInfo.Description
            };
```

Which is from [this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/439/how-to-list-all-windows-processes-and-their-attributes-task-manager-like-with-c-in-winforms), a custom *Taskmgr*.

I need to pass this variable to **Form 1**, but I couldn't make it public so I created

```
public static string[] Row;
Row = row;
```

So in **Form 1** I did the following: `string[] ROW = Form2.Row;` which actually doesn't lead to an error (and yep, if you ask me, these are very creative variable names).

---

But I need to store all the values of *Row* in *ROW*; I tried with

```
int Index = 1;

string[] ROW = new string[10];
ROW[Index] = AddForm.Row[];

Index++;
```

But I constantly get the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'".

**Solution:** add a 0 like this: `AddForm.Row[0];` it was clearly obvious, I thought I already tried, but that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the receiving index as well:

```
ROW[0] = AddForm.Row[0];
```

Depending on your logic, you can use indexes for the `0` s.

Answer (score 0):

ROW is of type `string[]` where as `AddForm.Row[0]` is of type `string`. I assume you meant to assign it to the first index of ROW which will be valid.

```
string[] ROW = new string[10];
ROW[0] = AddForm.Row[0];
```